# How to change from DW to DB correctly?

Tags: assembly, x86

My code right now looks like this:

```
; compute          /   |x+b|            , when c=a*x 
;              y = |   a^2-3b           , when c<a*x
;                  \   (2c-a)/(c+ax)    , when c>a*x  

stekas  SEGMENT STACK
    DB 256 DUP(0)
stekas  ENDS

duom    SEGMENT 
a   DB  -2 
b   DB  2
c   DW  6
x   DW -10,-8,-3,1,2,4
kiek    = ($-x)/2
y   DB kiek dup(0AAh)     
isvb    DB 'x=',6 dup (?), ' y=',6 dup (?), 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
perp    DB 'Overflow', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
daln    DB '0 division', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
netb    DB 'Overflow', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
spausk  DB 'Computing is over', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$' 
duom    ENDS

prog    SEGMENT
    assume ss:stekas, ds:duom, cs:prog
pr: MOV ax, duom
    MOV ds, ax
    XOR si, si      ; (sum mod 2) si = 0
    XOR di, di      ; di = 0
c_pr:   MOV cx, kiek
        JCXZ pab
cikl:
    MOV al, a
    CBW
    IMUL x[si]   
    CMP c, ax
    JE f2
    JL f3   
f1: MOV ax, c 
    MOV bx, 2 ; 2c
    IMUL bx
    JO kl1
    MOV bx, ax
    MOV al, a
    CBW
    XCHG ax, bx
    SUB ax, bx ; 2c-a
    MOV bx, ax
    MOV ax, x[si]
    IMUL a        ; a*x
    JO kl1
    ADD ax, c     ; a*x+c
    JO kl1
    XCHG ax, bx
    CWD 
    IDIV bx       ; (2c-a)/(a*x+c)
    JMP re
f3: MOV al, a
    CBW
    IMUL a
    JO kl1
    MOV bx, ax
    MOV ax, 3  
    IMUL b
    JO kl1
    XCHG ax, bx 
    SUB ax, bx
    JMP re
f2: MOV bx, x[si]
    MOV al, b
    CBW
    ADD ax, bx  ; x+b
    MOV bx, 0
    JO kl1
    CMP ax, 0
    JG mod
    NEG ax
mod:    ADD ax, bx ;2a+|c|
    JO kl1
re: 
    CMP al, 0
    JGE teigr 
    CMP ah, 0FFh 
    JE  ger
    JMP kl3
teigr:  CMP ah, 0 
        JE ger  
    JMP kl3
ger:    MOV y[di], al
    INC si
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP cikl
pab:                        
;============================
    XOR si, si
    XOR di, di 
        MOV cx, kiek
        JCXZ is_pab
is_cikl:
    MOV ax, x[si]   
    PUSH ax
    MOV bx, offset isvb+2  
    PUSH bx
    CALL binasc
    MOV al, y[di]
    CBW      
    PUSH ax
    MOV bx, offset isvb+11 
    PUSH bx
    CALL binasc

    MOV dx, offset isvb
    MOV ah, 9h
    INT 21h 
;============================
    INC si     
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP is_cikl
is_pab: 
;===== PAUZE ===================  
    LEA dx, spausk
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    MOV ah, 0 
        INT 16h 
;============================        
        MOV ah, 4Ch 
    INT 21h
;============================   

kl1:    LEA dx, perp
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    XOR al, al
    JMP ger
kl2:    LEA dx, daln
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    XOR al, al
    JMP ger
kl3:    LEA dx, netb
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    XOR al, al
    JMP ger

binasc  PROC NEAR   
    PUSH bp
    MOV bp, sp

    PUSHA  

    MOV cx, 6   
    MOV bx, [bp+4]
tarp:   MOV byte ptr[bx], ' '
    INC bx
    LOOP tarp

    MOV ax, [bp+6]
    MOV si, 10
    CMP ax, 0
    JGE val

    NEG ax
val:    XOR dx, dx
    DIV si

    ADD dx, '0'   ; galima--> ADD dx, 30h

    DEC bx
    MOV [bx], dl

    INC cx

    CMP ax, 0
    JNZ val

    MOV ax, [bp+6]
    CMP ax,0
    JNS teig

    DEC bx
    MOV byte ptr[bx], '-'
    INC cx
    JMP vepab

teig:   DEC bx
    MOV byte ptr[bx], '+'
    INC cx
vepab:  
    POPA  
    POP bp
    RET
binasc  ENDP    
prog    ENDS 
        END pr
```

I need to change x from DW to DB. This is how code looks like after my changes.

```
; compute          /   |x+b|            , when c=a*x 
;              y = |   a^2-3b           , when c<a*x
;                  \   (2c-a)/(c+ax)    , when c>a*x  

stekas  SEGMENT STACK
    DB 256 DUP(0)
stekas  ENDS

duom    SEGMENT 
a   DB  -2 
b   DB  2
c   DW  6
x   **DB** -10,-8,-3,1,2,4
kiek    = ($-x)/2
y   DB kiek dup(0AAh)     
isvb    DB 'x=',6 dup (?), ' y=',6 dup (?), 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
perp    DB 'Overflow', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
daln    DB '0 division', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
netb    DB 'Overflow', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$'
spausk  DB 'Computing is over', 0Dh, 0Ah, '$' 
duom    ENDS

prog    SEGMENT
    assume ss:stekas, ds:duom, cs:prog
pr: MOV ax, duom
    MOV ds, ax
    XOR si, si      ; (sum mod 2) si = 0
    XOR di, di      ; di = 0
c_pr:   MOV cx, kiek
        JCXZ pab
cikl:
    MOV al, a
    CBW
    IMUL x[si]   
    CMP c, ax
    JE f2
    JL f3   
f1: MOV ax, c 
    MOV bx, 2 ; 2c
    IMUL bx
    JO kl1
    MOV bx, ax
    MOV al, a
    CBW
    XCHG ax, bx
    SUB ax, bx ; 2c-a
    MOV bx, ax
    **MOV al, x[si]
    CBW**
    IMUL a        ; a*x
    JO kl1
    ADD ax, c     ; a*x+c
    JO kl1
    XCHG ax, bx
    CWD 
    IDIV bx       ; (2c-a)/(a*x+c)
    JMP re
f3: MOV al, a
    CBW
    IMUL a
    JO kl1
    MOV bx, ax
    MOV ax, 3  
    IMUL b
    JO kl1
    XCHG ax, bx 
    SUB ax, bx
    JMP re
f2: **MOV al, x[si]
    CBW
    MOV bx, ax**
    MOV al, b
    CBW
    ADD ax, bx  ; x+b
    MOV bx, 0
    JO kl1
    CMP ax, 0
    JG mod
    NEG ax
mod:    ADD ax, bx ;2a+|c|
    JO kl1
re: 
    CMP al, 0
    JGE teigr 
    CMP ah, 0FFh 
    JE  ger
    JMP kl3
teigr:  CMP ah, 0 
        JE ger  
    JMP kl3
ger:    MOV y[di], al
    INC si
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP cikl
pab:                        
;============================
    XOR si, si
    XOR di, di 
        MOV cx, kiek
        JCXZ is_pab
is_cikl:
    **MOV al, x[si]
    CBW**  
    PUSH ax
    MOV bx, offset isvb+2  
    PUSH bx
    CALL binasc
    MOV al, y[di]
    CBW      
    PUSH ax
    MOV bx, offset isvb+11 
    PUSH bx
    CALL binasc

    MOV dx, offset isvb
    MOV ah, 9h
    INT 21h 
;============================
    INC si     
    INC si
    INC di
    LOOP is_cikl
is_pab: 
;===== PAUZE ===================  
    LEA dx, spausk
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    MOV ah, 0 
        INT 16h 
;============================        
        MOV ah, 4Ch 
    INT 21h
;============================   

kl1:    LEA dx, perp
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    XOR al, al
    JMP ger
kl2:    LEA dx, daln
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    XOR al, al
    JMP ger
kl3:    LEA dx, netb
    MOV ah, 9
    INT 21h
    XOR al, al
    JMP ger

binasc  PROC NEAR   
    PUSH bp
    MOV bp, sp

    PUSHA  

    MOV cx, 6   
    MOV bx, [bp+4]
tarp:   MOV byte ptr[bx], ' '
    INC bx
    LOOP tarp

    MOV ax, [bp+6]
    MOV si, 10
    CMP ax, 0
    JGE val

    NEG ax
val:    XOR dx, dx
    DIV si

    ADD dx, '0'   ; galima--> ADD dx, 30h

    DEC bx
    MOV [bx], dl

    INC cx

    CMP ax, 0
    JNZ val

    MOV ax, [bp+6]
    CMP ax,0
    JNS teig

    DEC bx
    MOV byte ptr[bx], '-'
    INC cx
    JMP vepab

teig:   DEC bx
    MOV byte ptr[bx], '+'
    INC cx
vepab:  
    POPA  
    POP bp
    RET
binasc  ENDP    
prog    ENDS 
        END pr
```

I seperated places I edited with **
The problem is, that now loop actually is twice shorter. Before changes. Loop was executed six times, and now it is executed only three times with x values of -10, -3, 2 (it seems like one of two only)

I thought that the problem can be with kiek = ($-x)/2
I removed /2 from the end, but then it didn't helped. It started to show some random(I guess) x values.

What am I missing here? Where is the key factor that crashes my program when I try to change x from DW to DB?

Comment: Which loop is executing too few times?  IDK where to look in that wall of code with really short symbol names and few comments.  Oh, I see your `**` markers now.

Comment: Well, you're still incrementing `si` twice at the end of each loop (i.e. `si += sizeof(word)`)

Comment: Michael, you were right. Now loop is executed correct amount of times. But now my answers are wrong. Is there must be a problem where I output the result? Cause before changes actual computation f1,f2,f3 worked just fine.

Comment: Instead of a byte load followed by CBW, you can just use `movsx ax, [x+si]`.  A lot of your code looks inefficient (using slow instructions like `loop`, as well as excess instructions).  It's also confusing, since I think from the surrounding code that `mov ax, a` is a load, rather than a mov-immediate of the address.  In NASM syntax, you'd write `mov ax, [a]`, and I think that works in most assemblers.  Also, I think the comment is wrong for the c<a*x case, because the expression doesn't depend on x.  So you could just compute it once.

Comment: Likely the problems come from improper use of `cbw` and `cwd`. By reading the documentation, you can see they reference the same opcode. The proper way to sign-extend would be to use `movsx ax, al` or `movsx eax, ax` or similar for other registers.

Comment: You mean improper use of cbw and cwd inside f1: f2: f3?

Comment: @owacoder: This looks like 16bit code, but in any case the assembler will use (or omit) the operand-size prefix as necessary to get the right destination width.  `cbw` in 16bit code should assemble to `98`, while `cwde` assembles to `66 98`.  Note that `cwd` is a different instruction, and sign-extends ax into dx:ax.

Comment: When I try to use movsx program doesn't compile: illegal instruction or wrong parameters. I use emu8086

Comment: @PeterCordes - I have had program failures from trying to use both in the same piece of 32 bit code. I haven't tried with 16 bit though...

Comment: Do you not have an x86 desktop to run it natively?  Or set your emulator to emulate a more recent CPU.

Comment: It was a requirement in my university to use emu8086. And all this code is actually written by my teachers. I wrote f1-f3 and a part between cik1: and f1:

Comment: I guess those parts of code should likely be failing.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @owacoder: If you had problems, it might have been an assembler bug, or from you mixing up `cwd` with `cwde`.  There's no inherent problem with using the same opcode with or without the operand-size prefix to do the desired operation.

Comment: [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings#Added_in_specific_processors) that `movsx` was added with 386.  Learning 8086 asm instead of normal x86 asm is silly, IMO, because you learn to write code that has to swap everything into ax all the time.  Without 2-operand imul, and movsx, it just sucks.